Enable GPIO sysfs interface on Yocto Mickledore Linux Kernel
I'm trying to get my application to run on a new Yocto Mickledore Image I created. My application is failing to interface to the GPIO's and upon some research I found it is because GPIO sysfs interface is deprecated and GPIO chardev interface is now used (see here)
I really don't want to have to modify my application to make use of the new GPIO interface. Is there a way to configure my yocto image to make use of the old GPIO sysfs interface via /sys/class/gpio/export

According to Stop using /sys/class/gpio – it’s deprecated However the sysfs interface part of the GPIO subsystem is self-contained, selectable via the CONFIG_GPIO_SYSFS KConfig option and probably not causing any upkeep issues. It’s hard to imagine that this interface will be removed in the near future.  Looking at the HEAD of KConfig, the GPIO_SYSFS configuration option is still present.

Therefore, suggest try enabling CONFIG_GPIO_SYSFS in the Yocto image. This is a comment, and not an answer, since I haven't verified it will work.
